# Missing d3dx9_43.dll file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-c#-express-2010

I am making a game in Visual Studio and when I try to run it I get this error:

```
Unable to load DLL 'd3dx9_43.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

I have tried to reinstall some video drivers but that did not work.

Comment: Do you have the [last DirectX 9](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109) installed?

Comment: DirectX 9 is long ago obsolete. Make sure you really know what you are doing. Otherwise switch to Visual Studio 2015 and DirectX 11.

Comment: Thanks, all I needed was the Direct X